# Swift Firebase Sort By Distance From Post

Tags: swift, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, distance

---

I'm trying to sort the posts by the distance from the post to the current user.
My Firebase Database looks like this:

POST:

[image]

USER:

[image]

I did already achieve to sort my posts by the payment using this code

```
var REF_REQUESTS = Database.database().reference().child("requests")

func observeBestPaidRequests(completion: @escaping (Request) -> Void)
{
    REF_REQUESTS.queryOrdered(byChild: "pay").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
        {
            (snapshot) in
            let arraySnapshot = (snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]).reversed()
            arraySnapshot.forEach(
                {
                    (child) in
                    if let dict = child.value as? [String: Any]
                    {
                        let request = Request.transformRequest(dict: dict, key: snapshot.key)
                        completion(request)
                    }
            })
    })
}
```

But now I don't know and been struggling on this since about 1 week, how to sort it by the distance using the users and the location of the post.

Any ideas?
I would really appreciate an answer!

EDIT:

Code from the ViewController, where I'm trying to append it to the array and reload the tableView:

```
    @objc func loadBestPaidRequests()
{
    self.requests.removeAll()
    Api.requestApi.observeBestPaidRequests
        {
            (request) in
            guard let requesterId = request.uid
                else
            {
                return
            }

            self.fetchUser(uid: requesterId, completed:
                {
                    let requestLocation = CLLocation(latitude: request.latitude!, longitude: request.longitude!)
                    let distanceInMeters = requestLocation.distance(from: self.mapView.userLocation.location!)
                    let distanceInMetersUserFriendly = Double(round(1000*distanceInMeters/1000))

                    self.requests.append(request)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
    }
```

}

Comment: Assuming that the user is observing the requests node, every time there's a  new request that data is provided to the user. One solution would be to calculate the distance between user coords and the incoming coords from the request (Haversine?). Add that distance to a tableView dataSource, sort it ascending by distance distance and reload the tableView. That would then display the person that made the request and the distance from the user sorted by distance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how exactly do I sort it ascending by distance?

Comment: Given an array: myArray = [ 4, 2, 3, 1 ] you can use the Swift array sorting technique:  sortedArray = array.sorted { $0 < $1 }. All you need to do is to take the current users coords x0, y0 and the incoming request coords x1, y1, calculate the distance and add the results to the array. Then sort the array and reload the tableView.

Comment: I added some code to my question, could you pls take a look at It.

Comment: Never mind I got THANKS TO YOU man your awesome thank you so much!!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. I threw in a quick answer as well that outlines the process a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways to accomplish this task but here's what I would start with:

a class to keep track of requests and populate a tableView

```
class RequestClass {
  var requestId = ""
  var userId = ""
  var distance = ""
}

var requestsArray = [RequestClass]()
```

then observe the requests node (this is pseudo code but provides the concept)

```
requestsNode.observe(.childAdded.... { snapshot in 
   let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
   let reqId = snapshot.key
   let userId = dict["user_id"] as! String
   let long = dict["longitute"] as! Double
   let lat = dict["latitide"] as! Double

   let distance = //calc distance between this user position and incoming request position

   let request = RequestClass()
   request.requestId = regId
   request.userId = userId
   request.distance = distance

   self.requestsArray.append(request)
   self.requestsArray.sort { $0.distance < $1.distance }
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

with the above code, any time a new request comes in, the Firebase observe closure fires and calculates the distance between the user and the person making the request.

That request is added to an array and then sorted by distance and then the tableView used to display the data is updated.

You can expand on this to take in account a vehicle moving so it will automatically update the distance to all current requests etc.